# How to substract a list with terminal command?

Tags: email, terminal

I need a help, i have a List A with 100 emails (is a TXT) and the list B with another 100 emails.

I want to substract the similar emails from List A to List B and create a new file with the uniques emails.

how can i do that? i was looking for the command, but i cant find it.

The command i found is something like this:

```
diff file-1 file-2
```

I dont know if i need something else? also i try other methods, but i cant get with what i want...

I someone have idea how to do it i will appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For example here the information, in what environment you want to substract, is missing. Also how did you try to solve this problem?! For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sort -u -m *.txt -o file.txt
```

It will read all your `*.txt` files and merge them creating a `file.txt` with unique values.

Or you could create a unique file with all emails and then just remove duplicates by doing something like:

```
$ cat fileA.txt >> fileB.txt
$ sort -u fileB.txt -o file.txt
```